# connecting 2018 Mac Mini to 2 27" Thunderbolt displays

Tags: mac-mini, thunderbolt-display, daisy-chaining

I've currently got my 2018 Mac Mini connected to a 27" Thunderbolt display via [Thunderbolt 3 USB-C to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/apple-thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter-white/5687400.p?skuId=5687400) and a 27" Benq via HDMI. I have an opportunity to inherit (figuratively speaking) a 2nd Thunderbolt display and am contemplating replacing the Benq with it. My issues:

1. I don't want to have to drop $50 on the adapter. Is the Apple version the only one out there? I've found USB-C to Mini DP adapters for quite cheap but my understanding is that it *has* to be Thunderbolt... mDP alone will not cut it. Is this accurate?
2. As a measure to avoid the $50 hit in #1, can I daisy chain the 2 Thunderbolts? I believe I have a TB2 cable laying around. Otherwise, it looks like I'm stuck with a $30 hit for that... or is there a non-apple version I'm missing?

Comment: I believe the Thunderbolt display comes with a built-in thunderbolt cable. So, wouldn't you just plug this cable into the Thunderbolt jack on the other Thunderbolt display? In other words, you shouldn't need another Thunderbolt 2 cable or a Thunderbolt 3 to Thunderbolt 2 adaptor. Here is an example [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4idPJaQkOqI) where to two Thunderbolt displays are daisy chained (and the third is not). Also, you could have the two Thunderbolt displays and keep using the Benq as a third display.

Comment: @DavidAnderson - oh right right right. duh. So yes, as long as the daisy chaining works, I'm good to go without any additional cables. Can anyone confirm daisy chaining will work with the 2018 mac mini?

Comment: @DavidAnderson - I was previously running 3 (all connected directly to the Mac Mini)... downsized to a smaller desk and took one out of the equation. 3 was definitely overkill =)

Comment: I found that the fans ramped up all the time due to the Intel GPU struggling with too many pixels. (This, with one 5K display.)